# Sharekit not showing share options in Release Build Configuration Mode

Tags: objective-c, ios7, sharekit

When setting the Build Configuration to Release I see no share options as shown in the screenshot. But when I run the app with Build Configuration to Debug I see share options like Share on Facebook, etc.

Is there something I am missing? I am trying to build only for iOS7.

[image: No Options shown on Sharekit]

Comment: if you click more..., can you see sharers?

Comment: No but I found the issue. In the build configuration in Other Linker Flag I needed to add -ObjC